# Cloud Firebase Function to render Home Screen is it optimal?

Tags: google-cloud-functions

I have a fairly complex home screen built in `React Native` in which items are rendered in sections.

Section 1,
Section 2,
Section 3,
...Remaining items etc.

Each section has its own collection query and can get quite complex, thus I've decided to do the mapping and conditional logic within a [Firebase Cloud Function](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions).

My question is, considering cost and scaling is this optimal. Baring in mind this is the first api made when the user opens the app. So therefore, it must be robust.

I have already added;

```
.runWith({
  minInstances: 1,
  maxInstances: 2,
})
```

to the function to ensure at least one instance is running. However, as my user base grows will the minInstances required increase dramatically and incur heavy costs?

Answer (score 1):

> will the minInstances required increase dramatically and incur heavy costs?

Strictly speaking, minInstances isn't required at all, except by your own requirements for performance.  You're going to have to figure out if performance holds at the scale you're expecting.

We can't answer this for you, because we don't know the scale at which you're expecting usage, and we don't know the load on your function with that usage, and how that affects the performance of your site.  We can't say if or when it will be beneficial for you to change minInstances.  It's up to you to measure performance and choose to update your configuration in order to meet your own performance requirements.